# On what principle did Google's DeepMind learn to walk?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, q-learning, genetic-algorithms, deepmind

I just saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gn4nRCC9TwQ) on Youtube.

On what principle did Google's DeepMind learn to walk?

Was it Q-Learning or a Genetic Algorithm or Policy Gradient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full method is explained in the paper [Emergence of Locomotion Behaviours in Rich Environments](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.02286) by the DeepMind team.

Quoting from that paper:

> Using a novel scalable variant of policy gradient reinforcement learning, our agents learn to run, jump, crouch and turn as required
> by the environment . . .

So to answer your question, the researchers used a policy gradient method.